# Ударение в слове "проигранный"

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Как правильно поставить ударение: "прои́гранный" или "про́игранный"? (Второй вариант я часто слышал от шахматистов.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идёт о матче, который команда проиграла, то, конечно, **прои́гранный**. У шахматистов же есть *жаргонизм* с другим ударением, но обозначает он не партию, которую уже проиграли, а безнадёжную позицию в ещё играющейся партии - это условная оценка позиции, которую за пределами шахмат назвали бы "проигрышной" (жаргонизм совмещает оценочное значение этого слова с тем субъективным фактом, что шахматист своими действиями довёл игру до такой позиции). В шахматной среде во время турнира часто говорят в перерывах между сделанными ходами: "у тебя (у него) про́играно" (или "про́игранная позиция"). Это не мешает реально проигранные (законченные) кем-то партии в ретроспективе именовать прои́гранными.

Answer (score 0):

Нормативное ударение — прои́гранный. Вариант *про́игранный* неправилен.

Источник — "Орфоэпический словарь русского языка" под ред. Еськовой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополнительно — [Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x).

Comment: Вы сами всегда просите ссылочку. Я нашла: "Орфоэпический словарь под редакцией Резниченко", "Орфоэпический словарь Аванесова", "Орфоэпический словарь Ожегова"... Хотелось бы ВИДЕТЬ - из принципа - спорную Еськову. А потом уже и автору вопроса "поотмечаться". Извините... Если не в тягость..

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова прошу вас: http://www.ruslang.ru/agens.php?id=orfo14. Если что, это переработанный и дополненный словарь Аванесова ;)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Еськовой в сети нет. Ну, может, еще кто выложит... Конечно, ссылки лучше давать на Аванесова, Зарву или Резниченко. Но Еськова интересна тем, что она продолжает Аванесова.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60800/discussion-on-answer-by-aer----).

Answer (score 0):

Во всех мыслимых значениях правильно только про**и**гранный.
http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0458.htm

В отношении шахматного жаргонизма - не знаю, не сталкивался, хотя приходилось общаться, сам неплохо когда-то играл... 
Возможно, действительно смешение с "проигрышный".